# hyperref error when using XeLaTeX and fontspec with LaTeXmk

Tags: xetex, hyperref, fontspec, latexmk

I have defined a compilation tool for TeXWorks as follows:

```
Program: latexmk
Arguments: -e
           $xelatex=q/xelatex $synctexoption %0 %S/
           -pdf
           $fullname
```

It works fine in most cases, but I'm having problems with one file that imports the `hyperref` package. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[xetex,bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=headernfooter,urlcolor=headernfooter,linktoc=section,]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
hello, paper!
\end{document}
```

If I use the (predefined) XeLaTeX compilation tool instead, it works. If I comment the line importing `hyperref`, it works. But if I try to combine them, I get the following error message:

> ! Package hyperref Error: Wrong driver option `xetex',
>   (hyperref)                because XeTeX is not detected.

If I remove the `xetex` option and the import of `fontspec`, both work, but then I can't choose the fonts I want in my real document.

How do I combine these requirements?

Comment: Not that I'm having 100% success with hypertext, but my setup for XeLaTeX via latexmk says "$pdflatex=q/xelatex $synctexoption %O %S/" (Note the *pdflatex* rather than xelatex). But this was very much "monkey fingerpoken", I admit.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: I don't care if it was "monkey fingerpoken" - it solved my problem =D

Comment: LOL. Chee chee chee.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a `xetex` option for `hyperref`, but it's recommended not using it. In some cases it's necessary to pass `hyperref` an explicit driver option, but *not* when using

• LaTeX+`dvips`
• pdfLaTeX
• XeLaTeX
• LuaLaTeX

because in these cases `hyperref` is able to detect the driver automatically. The indication of the driver is necessary for

• LaTeX+`dvipdfmx`

or some other less common engines (VTeX, for instance).

Notice that the same holds for other commonly used packages whose behavior changes depending on the engine and driver used:

> `graphicx`, `color`, `xcolor`, `geometry`

don't need to be passed explicitly a driver name. For `geometry` it may be necessary when used alongside with `crop`.

However (thanks to Ulrike Fischer for pointing it out), a `xetex` options should do no harm if the engine used is `XeTeX` and raise an error otherwise. So in your case this means that `latexmk` is *not* using XeLaTeX for processing your document.

As Brent Longborought remarks, the argument to be passed to `latexmk` should be

```
$pdflatex=q/xelatex $synctexoption %0 %S/
```

(notice `pdflatex` just after the first `$` symbol).

Comment: There is a `xetex` option. `hyperref.sty` does contain the line `\DeclareVoidOption{xetex}`. `\usepackage[xetex]{hyperref}` works fine for me. It gives the error mentioned in the question if used when compiling with e.g. `pdflatex` – which indicates that latexmk is not using xetex.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extensive answer! It turns out that Brent was indeed the one to spot my problem - once I changed to `$pdflatex` instead of what I previously had, everything worked as expected.